# incresing counter in a recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have a question about the functionality of increasing values within a recursive function.

When I use:

`counter++` does not work

But when i use `counter + 1` It works correctly.

I also found another way for it to work: `++counter`, but I really could not understand what a difference it is to use the `++` before the counter.

Example:

```
printEachName = (companyNames, newPeople, counter, callback) => {
  if (companyNames.length === newPeople.length) {
    return callback(false, companyNames);
  }
  console.log('counter >>> ', counter);
  let newP = newPeople[counter];

  companyNames.push(newP.name);
  printEachName(companyNames, newPeople, counter + 1, callback);
}

printEachName([], newPeople, 0, (errorPrinting, response) => {
  if (errorPrinting) {
    //res.send()
    return;
  }

  console.log('response is >>> ', response);
});
```

Comment: @Luis, `counter++` is not the same as `counter = counter + 1`. `counter++` is something more like `temp = counter, counter = counter + 1, temp`. Try this in the JavaScript console and you'll see `counter = 123; foo = (temp = counter, counter = counter + 1, temp)`.  `foo` will be 123`, `counter` will be 124

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `counter++`, `++counter` and `counter + 1` are three completely different things.

Explained with examples:

```
function f(n) { console.log(n); }
var counter = 0;

// Call f(counter) and then increment counter after
f(counter++);  
// log: 0
// counter: 1

// Increment counter and then call f(counter)
f(++counter);
// log: 2
// counter: 2

// Call f() with the value counter+1, do not alter counter
f(counter + 1);
// log: 3
// counter: 2
```

The `+ 1` approach works because you're correctly supplying the incremented value to the function call. The prefix increment would work as well, but as `counter` is not used anywhere else this just over-complicates things. The postfix version is never going to work.

Answer (score 5):

Try `++counter`. Using a [prefix increment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators#Increment_and_decrement) will first increment the variable then pass it to the function. Do note this is different from `counter + 1` which does **not** change its value.

Answer (score 1):

This probably has been already answered, but `a++` takes the value `a` and use it *and then* increment the value. On the other hand `++a` increments the value of `a` first and then use the incremented value (equivalent to `a + 1` in your particular example).

Answer (score 1):

++ before variable is pre-increment operator,whereas ++ after variable is post-increment operator.

In

```
printEachName(companyNames, newPeople, counter++, callback);
```

counter's value is updated after the printEachName() is executed.

whereas in

```
printEachName(companyNames, newPeople, ++counter, callback);
```

counter's value is updated instantly i.e. even before the printEachName() is actually executed.

But when you use

```
printEachName(companyNames, newPeople, counter + 1, callback);
```

then counter's value isn't updated at all.But counter+1 is passed as parameter to the function.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to everyone else's explanations

```
counter++
```

Is equivalent to this

```
temp = counter, counter = counter + 1, temp
```

You can try it here to see

```js
var counter1 = 123;
var foo1 = counter1++;

console.log("counter1:", counter1, "foo1:", foo1);

var counter2 = 123;
var foo2 = (temp = counter2, counter2 = counter2 + 1, temp);

console.log("counter2:", counter2, "foo2:", foo2);
```

`variable++` is a post increment. In other words return the value that was in the variable, **then** increment.

If you really want to just increment you just arguably use `++variable`